# How to change the combination of the "@" on linux

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

as per title I would to change the combination of the @ from: altgr+@key to: ctrl+alt+@key as on windows like to speak.

Is it possible or too complicated that it is better to keep the default combinations?

I don't know if this information is needed but when in doubt I'll put it all the same: I have the 20.04 version of ubuntu and I'm using an Italian layout.

Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

The @ character is available as a 3:rd level symbol on many keyboard layouts, including the Italian one. And <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is the default key to access such symbols.

You can define some other key to serve that purpose, but as far as I know it's not possible to define a key combination such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Maybe, if you clarify ***why*** you want to change it, I might be able to propose a solution.

Comment: If you tell me you can't put ctrl + alt then there's nothing to do...
The reason is simply habit since, coming from windows, to make the @ you use the combination ctrl + alt + @ key (at least with the Italian layout)
Thank you anyway!